# Multiple comparisons of parameters from non-linear regression

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, nonlinear-regression

I want to compare parameters a_i and b_i estimated by nonlinear regression (y=a_i*x/(b_i+x)) for different data-sets (let's say 8 different data sets).

I have calculated the non-linear regression and obtained a and b for each data set individually, and I have actually compared data-set pairs by t-tests.
The next step would be the multiple comparison of the whole bunch of data-sets, to see e.g. if some of them group together etc.

However, I am quite bad at statistics, so I really don't have a clue how to start. I've been reading up and down the internet on different methods, but have not found a solution that I was able to understand (actually, I do get more confused all the time).

Can anybody help me with my problem? Maybe in a way that also dummies like me understand it?